# Declaring Keycodes as strings

Tags: unity, c#

How do I declare the keycodes as strings instead of selecting the keys from a list? Such that the user can input a key in inspector window and it will be read?

```
public string StringKey = "a";

void Update () {

   if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.StringKey)) {

   }
```

Comment: It seems like you want to reinvent a feature Unity already has out-of-the-box. Have you considered to just have the developer set up semantic key mappings in the Input Window? (Edit -> Project Settings -> Input)

Comment: But that is lot of work for every Unity editor application. I am just trying to implement a script that does it.

Comment: Does this question from Stackoverflow help you? [Convert a string to an enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Input.GetKeyDown has an override that accepts strings directly, so I'm not sure why you'd even need to convert to keycodes? [The list of strings it accepts is documented here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html)

Answer (score 1):

As Phillipp mentioned, `Enum.Parse`, I used the following and it worked:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown((KeyCode) System.Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), StringKey))) {
...
```